# Is "al dettagli" correct?

Tags: plural

This sentence appears in https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano-Inglese/S/scemare.html:

Questo mese le vendite al dettagli sono scemate.

But doesn't "al" go with the singular:  al dettaglio?  If it's "dettagli", shouldn't it be "ai dettagli"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You are perfectly right: it's *al dettaglio*. The plural would be *ai dettagli*, but while *al dettaglio* is (also) an idiom to refer to retail prices, retailing etc., *ai dettagli* could only be used with the main meaning of *dettaglio*, for instance in a sentence like *Gianni è molto attento ai dettagli*.

<sub>Personal remark: _La Repubblica_, which used to be an important and almost pioneering Italian newspaper, has been constantly declining in both form and substance. It would almost seem as if its carelessness extended even to reference works they just host.</sub>